# Angular 2+ onmouseover event on returned html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method in my `component.ts` that returns some html like this:

```
someMethod() {
    return `
      <div>hello</div>
    `;
}
```

I would like to return a div with a mouseover event but It seems like the angular way of `(mouseenter)="myFunction()"` doesnt work. Probably since it is returned html and that is not compiled.

```
someMethod() {
    return `
      <div (mouseenter)="myFunction()">hello</div>
    `;
}
```

So I found that doing the regular javascript way `onmouseover="myFunction()"` does indeed trigger the function:

```
someMethod() {
    return `
      <div onmouseover="myFunction()">hello</div>
    `;
}
```

But the issue with this, is that I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

`myFunction()` is a method in the same `component.ts` file as `someMethod()` which returns the html

How can I fix my issue, or is there another way to write this?

Comment: Why do you want add the html template from ts file ?

Comment: I am using a library that generates the html for me. I dont have access to this html to modify it

Comment: It would be tricky in this case. You either need to wrap the library with customised Angular code or get rid of that library. I would suggest the latter option.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is to render the Angular html template which will be served as string value ( it might come from DB ).

### Bad News

Its not the way you are doing right now. Just getting the string value from the ts file binding to html is not going to work since Angular doesn't compile the template while binding.

### Good News

Its possible in Angular but not a easy way though. If you really want to implement this functionality and use widely then definitely worth sparing time on it.

Here is the `RuntimeContentComponent` which helps to compile the Angular template

### runtime-content.component.ts

```
import { 
    Component,
    ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef,
    Compiler, ComponentFactory, NgModule, ModuleWithComponentFactories, ComponentFactoryResolver
} from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'runtime-content',
    template: `
        <div>
            <h3>Template</h3>
            <div>
                <textarea rows="5" [(ngModel)]="template"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button (click)="compileTemplate()">Compile</button>
            <h3>Output</h3>
            <div #container></div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class RuntimeContentComponent {

    template: string = '<div>\nHello, {{name}}\n</div>';

    @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
    container: ViewContainerRef;

    private componentRef: ComponentRef<{}>;

    constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private compiler: Compiler) {
    }

    compileTemplate() {

        let metadata = {
            selector: `runtime-component-sample`,
            template: this.template
        };

        let factory = this.createComponentFactorySync(this.compiler, metadata, null);

        if (this.componentRef) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
            this.componentRef = null;
        }
        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    }

    private createComponentFactorySync(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component, componentClass: any): ComponentFactory<any> {
        const cmpClass = componentClass || class RuntimeComponent { name: string = 'Denys' };
        const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

        @NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
        class RuntimeComponentModule { }

        let module: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any> = compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(RuntimeComponentModule);
        return module.componentFactories.find(f => f.componentType === decoratedCmp);
    }

}
```

### Link

Please refer this excellent article to get the complete details - https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36

Comment: thanks for this answer! I'll try to implement this right now, ill let you know what happens

Answer (score 1):

Angular `(event)` won't work because template isn't compiled by angular and as far as I know there is no possibility for that. You would have to define component or directive for this before building project. The other way is harder but it can do the trick

You should first "`compile`" the html string, and then bind it via grabbing specific element and use `addEventListener`.

```
someMethod() {
    const stringifiedHTML = `
      <div onmouseover="myFunction()">hello</div>
    `;
    // create an empty div that will hold
    // stringified html and convert it to actual tree
    const div = document.createElement('div'); 
    // this will convert stringifiedHTML to acutal node tree
    div.innerHTML = stringifiedHTML;
    const resultHTML = div.firstElementChild;
    // now find exactly element you want to bind and do it with addEventListener
}
```